# Get number and body of a whatsapp message in twilio with java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, twilio

I have a problem that i am trying to solve. I have this messages coming from WhatsApp that i am trying to reply using the Twilio SDK for java.

This is my code:

```
package com.boilerplate.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;

@Controller
@Repository
@Transactional
@RequestMapping("/boilerplate")
public class BoilerplateController {
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "";
    @Autowired 
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/wizard" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String wizardSave(@RequestParam String from,@RequestParam String body) { 

//      String q1_field = "0";
//      String q2_field = "0";
//      String q3_field = "0";
//      String q4_field = "0";
    String undone = "UNDONE";
//      String status = "";

        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        Message message = Message.creator(
                 new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(from),
                 new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+14155238886"),
                "Hello there!")
            .create();
        return undone;


}
}
```

For some reason this code

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/wizard" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String wizardSave(@RequestParam String from,@RequestParam String body) {
```

does not get me the from and body that i require.

I am using spring and i have used the annotation @RequestParam

I cannot get the from and the body. Why?.

NB: The only i error i get is from Twilio saying i am unable to connect.

Comment: `does not get me the from and body that i require.` Can you post what you do get and what you expect to get?

Comment: the from and body are what twilio api provides. They share the name across the api i guess but the variables in my case are empty.

Comment: Is body really a requestParam? Not a RequestBody? It's hard to tell without seeing twilio api endpoint.

Comment: Are you sure you want to share your account and auth token in clear?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it this way

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/wizard" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String wizardSave(@RequestParam("Body") String message, 
    @RequestParam("From") String from) {
```

and to send

```
  Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
                    Message messagem = Message.creator(
                             new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(from),
                             new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+14155238886"),
                            "Sent From one")
                        .create();
   System.out.println(messagem.getSid());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   @PostMapping(value="/wizard",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String wizardSave(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> data) {
    String body= data.getFirst("Body");

    System.out.prinln("Body :"+body);

    return body;
}
```

Hope this solution will be useful.